# Gradle build failed after updating android studio to 4.2 Beta1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I've just updated android studio and can't build my previous project.
I've encountered these errors:

```
class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I'm kinda new to the android studio my version of java is:

```
java version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
```

and build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appName"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
//        vectorDrawables{
//            useSupportLibrary true
//        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

sorry for the long and messy question. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same thing happened to me today, I just uninstalled and reinstalled the stable version for now.

Comment: Tnx  @David Kroukamp I've done the same It's working fine now

Comment: @PersianBuddy I also upgraded to 4.2 and not all my units fail. It passes Jenkins/Github CI though. When I roll back to 4.1.3, all the unit tests pass. Something is up with 4.2 IDE, however, it is curious that more people aren't running into issues.

Have you since upgraded back to 4.2? And if so, were you able to resolve these conflicts you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `build/` method and running the daemon again

Comment: It didn't work. I've uninstalled the V4.2 Beta and reinstalled V4.1 and it's okay now. tnx 4 your answer

Comment: Please put an upvote to the answer, seems like StackOverflow has banned me from posting
Or mark it as accepted if you want

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for a while and I recommend to uninstall the previous version. Exprot your settings if needed. Install AS via the exe file in the links, because the zip will produce the same error. I have not tried making a fresh install without uninstalling, but any feedback is appreciated if that method works.
Links:
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Answer (score 0):

Had the same with Android Studio 4.2.1. Uninstalling it and then installing it again helped me.

Answer (score -5):

The error already explains the reasons and fixes to possible problems. if the above mentioned answer by @gtxtreme does not work, try closing android studio and restart your system.

Though it is recommended that you work with stable version of android studio which is 4.1 and leave the testing of beta 4.2 to the experts

Comment: Yes, you're right @Bilal BWS I shouldn't install its Beta version in the first place. by the way restarting won't work. I've uninstalled it.

Comment: As an expert developer of over 20 years, with sporadic Java experience since last millennium, I am still surprised by how bad the state of this tooling is.  I'd rather get a clue to what is wrong and how to fix it than find such self-superior comments, so get over yourself and try helping solve rather than dismiss if commenting!